# CodeIgniter Pagination - Page links acting weird

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Ok, I have been at this for the past hour and CAN NOT for the life of me figure this out.
It's getting the page count correct.. like I should have two pages right now.  I am limiting it at 5 right now and have 7 results. However, when I click on page 2, it doesn't show the other two postings.
Right now, my forum URLs are like this:
forum/category/2 (forum controller, category method, 2 for the category ID)
I would think the pages then go as follows: forum/category/2/1 for page 1 and forum/category/2/2 for page 2 and such.. however, page 2 is giving me this as the URL:

forum/category/5... which category ID 5 has no topics in it.. but it should be leading to the second page of category ID 2! So I'm unsure... It might be showing 5 since it's only showing 5 per page?? Not sure how that works, but here is my following code:

```
public function category($id, $page = NULL) {
    //grab topics
    parent::before();
    $data['forum_title'] = $this->forum->get_cat($id);
    $data['id'] = $id;

    $config = array();
    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'forum/category/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->forum->topic_count($id);
    $config['per_page'] = 5;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 4;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment'])) ? $this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment']) : 0;
    $data['topics_array'] = $this->forum->get_topics($id, $config['per_page'], $page);

    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('forum/category', $data);
    parent::after();
}
```

Here is my functions that are used in that controller:

```
//count the topics in a certain category id for pagination
public function topic_count($id) {
    $this->db->where('cat_id', $id);
    $this->db->from('forum_topic');

    return $this->db->count_all_results();

}
//get all topics in a certain category
public function get_topics($id, $limit, $start) {
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('t.id, t.title, t.sticky, t.locked, u.username as author, COUNT(p.id) as postcount, (SELECT u.username
        FROM forum_post fp
        INNER JOIN user u ON fp.author_id = u.user_id
        WHERE fp.topic_id = t.id
        ORDER BY fp.date DESC
        LIMIT 1) as lposter, (SELECT fp.date
        FROM forum_post fp
        WHERE fp.topic_id = t.id
        ORDER BY fp.date DESC
        LIMIT 1) as lastdate');
    $this->db->from('forum_topic t');
    $this->db->join('user u', 'u.user_id = t.author_id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('forum_post p', 'p.topic_id = t.id', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('t.cat_id', $id);
    $this->db->group_by('t.id, t.title, t.sticky, t.locked, author, lposter, lastdate');
    $this->db->order_by('t.sticky desc, p.date desc');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

Comment: I was faced same problem and then handle from jquery. check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025993/pagination-current-link-not-highlighting/32863062#32863062

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$config['uri_segment']` is used by CI to determine current page, not to generate links.

Try this:

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url('forum/category/' . $id);
```