# Pagination current link not highlighting

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, pagination

I got a strange problem, my current pagination link is not highlighted the pagination urls I made looks like:

```
site.com/list/50/?some=value
```

Everything is working great, but the current pagination link in view is not highlighted. I checked CSS and it's ok, the problem comes from the library I guess.

This is my code. I can't see anything wrong in here:

```
$pagination['base_url'] = site_url('asd');
    if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] !==''){
    $pagination['suffix'] = '/?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }
    $pagination['first_url'] = site_url('asd');
    $pagination['total_rows'] = $total_rows[0]->total;
    $pagination['first_link'] = '&nbsp;First&nbsp;';
    $pagination['last_link'] = '&nbsp;Last&nbsp;';
    $pagination['next_link']  = '&nbsp;Next&nbsp;';
    $pagination['prev_link']  = '&nbsp;Prev&nbsp;';
    $pagination['num_links'] = 5;

    $this->pagination->initialize($pagination);
```

Any clue appreciated.

i post my library which i edited for markup also:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * CodeIgniter
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP 5.1.6 or newer
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008 - 2011, EllisLab, Inc.
 * @license     http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/license.html
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com
 * @since       Version 1.0
 * @filesource
 */

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Pagination Class
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  Libraries
 * @category    Pagination
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html
 */
class CI_Pagination {

    var $base_url           = ''; // The page we are linking to
    var $prefix         = ''; // A custom prefix added to the path.
    var $suffix         = ''; // A custom suffix added to the path.

    var $total_rows         = ''; // Total number of items (database results)
    var $per_page           = 10; // Max number of items you want shown per page
    var $num_links          =  2; // Number of "digit" links to show before/after the currently viewed page
    var $cur_page           =  0; // The current page being viewed
    var $first_link         = '&lsaquo; First';
    var $next_link          = '&gt;';
    var $prev_link          = '&lt;';
    var $last_link          = 'Last &rsaquo;';
    var $uri_segment        = 3;
    var $full_tag_open      = '<p class="CI-pagination">';
    var $full_tag_close     = '</p>';
    var $first_tag_open     = '<span class="pagination-first">';
    var $first_tag_close            = '&nbsp;</span>';
    var $last_tag_open      = '<span class="pagination-last">&nbsp;';
    var $last_tag_close     = '</span>';
    var $first_url          = ''; // Alternative URL for the First Page.
    var $cur_tag_open       = '<span class="pagination-current">&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-small">';
    var $cur_tag_close      = '</a></span>';
    var $next_tag_open      = '<span class="pagination-next">&nbsp;';
    var $next_tag_close     = '&nbsp;</span>';
    var $prev_tag_open      = '<span class="pagination-prev">&nbsp;';
    var $prev_tag_close     = '</span>';
    var $num_tag_open       = '<span class="pagination-num">&nbsp;';
    var $num_tag_close      = '</span>';
    var $page_query_string          = FALSE;
    var $query_string_segment       = 'per_page';
    var $display_pages      = TRUE;
    var $anchor_class       = 'btn btn-small';

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   array   initialization parameters
     */
    public function __construct($params = array())
    {
        if (count($params) > 0)
        {
            $this->initialize($params);
        }

        if ($this->anchor_class != '')
        {
            $this->anchor_class = 'class="'.$this->anchor_class.'" ';
        }

        log_message('debug', "Pagination Class Initialized");
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Initialize Preferences
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   array   initialization parameters
     * @return  void
     */
    function initialize($params = array())
    {
        if (count($params) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($params as $key => $val)
            {
                if (isset($this->$key))
                {
                    $this->$key = $val;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Generate the pagination links
     *
     * @access  public
     * @return  string
     */
    function create_links()
    {
        // If our item count or per-page total is zero there is no need to continue.
        if ($this->total_rows == 0 OR $this->per_page == 0)
        {
            return '';
        }

        // Calculate the total number of pages
        $num_pages = ceil($this->total_rows / $this->per_page);

        // Is there only one page? Hm... nothing more to do here then.
        if ($num_pages == 1)
        {
            return '';
        }

        // Determine the current page number.
        $CI =& get_instance();

        if ($CI->config->item('enable_query_strings') === TRUE OR $this->page_query_string === TRUE)
        {
            if ($CI->input->get($this->query_string_segment) != 0)
            {
                $this->cur_page = $CI->input->get($this->query_string_segment);

                // Prep the current page - no funny business!
                $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ($CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment) != 0)
            {
                $this->cur_page = $CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment);

                // Prep the current page - no funny business!
                $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
            }
        }

        $this->num_links = (int)$this->num_links;

        if ($this->num_links < 1)
        {
            show_error('Your number of links must be a positive number.');
        }

        if ( ! is_numeric($this->cur_page))
        {
            $this->cur_page = 0;
        }

        // Is the page number beyond the result range?
        // If so we show the last page
        if ($this->cur_page > $this->total_rows)
        {
            $this->cur_page = ($num_pages - 1) * $this->per_page;
        }

        $uri_page_number = $this->cur_page;
        $this->cur_page = floor(($this->cur_page/$this->per_page) + 1);

        // Calculate the start and end numbers. These determine
        // which number to start and end the digit links with
        $start = (($this->cur_page - $this->num_links) > 0) ? $this->cur_page - ($this->num_links - 1) : 1;
        $end   = (($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages) ? $this->cur_page + $this->num_links : $num_pages;

        // Is pagination being used over GET or POST?  If get, add a per_page query
        // string. If post, add a trailing slash to the base URL if needed
        if ($CI->config->item('enable_query_strings') === TRUE OR $this->page_query_string === TRUE)
        {
            $this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url).'&amp;'.$this->query_string_segment.'=';
        }
        else
        {
            $this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url, '/') .'/';
        }

        // And here we go...
        $output = '';

        // Render the "First" link
        if  ($this->first_link !== FALSE AND $this->cur_page > ($this->num_links + 1))
        {
            $first_url = ($this->first_url == '') ? $this->base_url : $this->first_url;
            $output .= $this->first_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$first_url.'">'.$this->first_link.'</a>'.$this->first_tag_close;
        }

        // Render the "previous" link
        if  ($this->prev_link !== FALSE AND $this->cur_page != 1)
        {
            $i = $uri_page_number - $this->per_page;

            if ($i == 0 && $this->first_url != '')
            {
                $output .= $this->prev_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->first_url.'">'.$this->prev_link.'</a>'.$this->prev_tag_close;
            }
            else
            {
                $i = ($i == 0) ? '' : $this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix;
                $output .= $this->prev_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->base_url.$i.'">'.$this->prev_link.'</a>'.$this->prev_tag_close;
            }

        }

        // Render the pages
        if ($this->display_pages !== FALSE)
        {
            // Write the digit links
            for ($loop = $start -1; $loop <= $end; $loop++)
            {
                $i = ($loop * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page;

                if ($i >= 0)
                {
                    if ($this->cur_page == $loop)
                    {
                        $output .= $this->cur_tag_open.$loop.$this->cur_tag_close; // Current page
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $n = ($i == 0) ? '' : $i;

                        if ($n == '' && $this->first_url != '')
                        {
                            $output .= $this->num_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->first_url.'">'.$loop.'</a>'.$this->num_tag_close;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $n = ($n == '') ? '' : $this->prefix.$n.$this->suffix;

                            $output .= $this->num_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->base_url.$n.'">'.$loop.'</a>'.$this->num_tag_close;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Render the "next" link
        if ($this->next_link !== FALSE AND $this->cur_page < $num_pages)
        {
            $output .= $this->next_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->base_url.$this->prefix.($this->cur_page * $this->per_page).$this->suffix.'">'.$this->next_link.'</a>'.$this->next_tag_close;
        }

        // Render the "Last" link
        if ($this->last_link !== FALSE AND ($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages)
        {
            $i = (($num_pages * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page);
            $output .= $this->last_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->base_url.$this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix.'">'.$this->last_link.'</a>'.$this->last_tag_close;
        }

        // Kill double slashes.  Note: Sometimes we can end up with a double slash
        // in the penultimate link so we'll kill all double slashes.
        $output = preg_replace("#([^:])//+#", "\\1/", $output);

        // Add the wrapper HTML if exists
        $output = $this->full_tag_open.$output.$this->full_tag_close;

        return $output;
    }
}
// END Pagination Class

/* End of file Pagination.php */
/* Location: ./system/libraries/Pagination.php */
```

According to my pagination library, all my pagination links are printed out as `class="pagination-num"` and the `class="pagination-current"` is added only to the first pagination link , unbelievable :/

When changing page, the pagination looks always as shown in this image, no changes between a page to another :/

[image]

Comment: have you add any css class for current link if not add this to pagination config $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<span class="current">' and $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</span>'; you can use any tag

Comment: @umefarooq sure i added both for current,next,prev, etc , the problem is they are not switched and they look all the same when printing pagination links :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Read this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html) and find the "Customizing the "Current Page" Link" section. Use that to add custom markup then add appropriate CSS.

Edit: the OP found the following solution:

```
$pagination['uri_segment'] = 2;
```

Comment: already done, but that is not the problem all my links are outputted as class="pagination-num" , check my answer updates please

Comment: @sbaaaang Check the rendered html code, does it show the correct CSS? Are you loading the correct CSS file (is the css being added to the page)? If both are yes, maybe you have some css overwriting this style, trying using !important or use something like firebug to review the css to see all the styles being applied to the span.

Comment: yes already checked all, please check the image i posted above , everytime i change the page the pagination links looks as shown in the image, no changes i mean :/

Comment: Is the pagination links actually working? Maybe it is failing and loading page one each time. When you go to page two, the html code shows the current span tag on #2 correct?

Comment: the pagination links are ok, and results are returned by offset, i mean pagination works, but links are fixed as shown in the image :/ , it doesn't highlights the right current link, it always highlight first_url :/

Comment: If the page is changing and the correct data is being show (different pages) then the problem is either the CSS being overwritten, or the span class is being applied to the wrong number. You have to figure out which one.

Comment: but the pagination is adding the same css class to all links , also to the current so it's pagination getting confused :(

Comment: What version of code igniter is this? Maybe it was a bug, can you copy the pagination file from the newest version and see if that changes anything?

Comment: tryed but the problem seems to persists :/

Comment: ok i fixed dude :/ sorry i missed  $pagination['num_links'] = 5;
    $pagination['uri_segment'] = 2;

Comment: @sbaaaang `$pagination['uri_segment']` this son of a b**** was my nightmare. I spent several hours to find WHY.

Comment: @HashemQolami yeah, damn, it happens :/ nice that you fixed now!

Answer (score 1):

Add these line and write css for .current class

```
$pagination['cur_tag_open'] = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="current">';

$pagination['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
$pagination['cur_page'] = {put current page no here};
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your **$config['uri_segment']**. Otherwise handle from jquery. Do somethings like:-

Suppose your link:-

```
<div id="my-ci-link"><?php echo $links; ?></div>
```

write jQuery:-

```
$('#my-ci-link strong').css('color','green');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<pre>
    if ($this->uri->segment(2))
                $data['page'] = $this->uri->segment(2);
            else
                $data['page'] = 0;
            $config["cur_page"] = $data['page'];
    ...
</pre>
```